# Same Model with different columns Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, devise

I have 2 user roles `Developer` and `Driver`. They both are under an `User` model, but also both have different details such as Developer has `hourly_rate`, `skills`, `experience`, `full_name` and Driver has `cars_he_can_drive`, `hours_driven`, `full_name` etc.

They have some common columns and some different ones as well. Should there be a separate detail table (`develop_details`, `driver_details`) for each of the User? and further, relationships can be made with them.

Else I can have same model with all columns and fetch only the ones required (others will be nil ofcourse).

**UPDATE**
Im using role as and integer in user table and then using enums.
I'm using Rails 5 with devise 4.3.0.

Comment: you can easily adapt your current roles using `enum` to single table inheritance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want to look at Single Table Inheritance

Try a `Developer` and `Driver` that both inherit from `User` and share one `users` database table. Each is effectively its own model, allowing you to define totally independent associations, callbacks, validations, instance methods, etc...

They share all of the same database columns, and anything defined in the `User` class will be inherited (and can be overwritten).

You will need to add a `type` column to `users`. All of the `Developer` and `Driver` columns fields should be defined for the `users` table as well.

```
class AddTypeColumnToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :type, :string
  end
end
```

And your models

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
end

class Driver < User
end

class Developer < User
end

Driver.new.type # => "Driver"
Developer.new.type # => "Developer"
User.new.type # => nil
User.new(type: 'Driver').class # => Driver
User.new(type: 'Developer').class # => Developer
User.new.class # => User
```

You can run separate queries for them just as you would any other model

```
Developer.all # queries all users WHERE type="Developer"
Driver.all # queries all users WHERE type="Driver"
User.all # queries all users no matter what type
```

Write your associations just as you would with any other model, and ActiveRecord will take care of everything else.

```
class Company < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :users
  has_many :developers
  has_many :drivers
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :company
end

class Driver < User
  belongs_to :company
end

class Developer < User
  belongs_to :company
end

c = Company.first
c.developers # => All developers that belong to the Company
c.drivers # => All drivers that belong to the Company
c.users # => All users (including developers and drivers) that belong to the Company
```

You can also use `enum` for the `type` column, and override the default `type` column name if you wish

```
class AddTypeColumnToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :role, :integer
  end
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  self.inheritance_column = :role # This overrides the the "type" column name default

  enum role: { Driver: 0, Developer: 1 }
end

class Driver < User
end

class Developer < User
end
```

The catch with using `enum` is you will have to use the capitalized name, and all of your `enum` helper methods and scopes will be capitalized as well.

```
User.Driver # => Scope that returns all drivers
Driver.all # => same as User.Driver
User.first.Driver? # => Is the user a Driver?
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Inheritance.html

http://siawyoung.com/coding/ruby/rails/single-table-inheritance-in-rails-4.html

Comment: @Jonathan fair enough, improved the answer. thanks for the feedback

Comment: Awesome job!  I just remove my flag.

Comment: Thank you! Still new around here : )

Comment: @simon Thanks for the answer! What if i dont want to use type as a string but else want to go for a column type as integer and declaring enums in User model?

Comment: @TalhaMeh was this helpful?

Comment: @m.simonborg For my case,  yes its suits best i guess.

Comment: @TalhaMeh if you feel like it appropriately answers your question please accept the answer : )

Answer (score 0):

Well both approach will solve your problem. Personally I will only have a single table because `Developer` is also type of `User` and `Driver` is also type of `User`. You can do something like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class Developer < User
end

class Driver < User 
end
```

If user is Developer then you can fetch extra columns for developers. It's fine to have few column with nil value.

Comment: Thanks and by doing so, i'll be able to validate what i need to.

Answer (score 0):

You can decide this based on the number of different columns. If the number of different columns is more which seems to be the case here, Create a user table which contains all the common columns and 2 more tables(developers and drivers) which will contain a user_id to map with the user.

Also create a table named roles. Roles will contain id and role_name(driver, developer etc.) and add role_id column in users table. This structure will give you the flexibility even if you have more than 2 roles.

`class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 end`

`class Driver < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
 end`

`class Developer < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
 end`

`class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
 end`

Comment: Thanks. That'd cost in db queries. Single table inheritance seems to be more robust solution.

Comment: Yeah, I agree with that, but if you want to increase more roles in future, you'd end up wasting a lot of space due to a lot of empty columns(a lot of null columns). If you don't have a lot of different columns or more roles then you can go ahead with Single table inheritance.