# Conditional model validations based on a role

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have roles for users implemented with an enum in the user model:

```
enum role: [:staff, :clinician]
```

I have a University model with the User belongs_to :university and a University model with has_many :users.

The way that my app will work is that "staff" will belong to a university, but "clinicians" are private practice and therefore do not need to belong to a university and need not select one during signup.

I have my signup form set up to hide the university field if the user selects Clinician, but I want to make sure that my validations are set up to require that any user who selects staff on signup must also select a university and that any user who selects clinician on signup fails validation if they select a university.

Here's the role section of the user signup form:

```
<%= f.label :role %>
      <%= f.select(:role, User.roles.keys.map {|role| [role.titleize,role]}, :include_blank => "Please Select", id: 'user_role')  %>

      <%= content_tag :div, class: 'js-dependent-fields', data: { 'select-id': 'user_role', 'option-value': 'staff'} do %>
      <%= f.label :university_id%>
      <%= collection_select( :user, :university_id, University.all, :id, :name, prompt: true) %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It requires a bit more extra setup but I think pays off in flexibility over time:

Try Single Table Inheritance combined with your enum roles. You'll be able to more easily define separate callbacks, validations, scopes, and associations for your different roles, while inheriting the ones you want them to share in common. For example, you could just make it so only `Staff belongs_to :university`, and `Clinician` does not.

```
# Stripped down schema

create_table "universities", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end

create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  t.bigint "university_id"
  t.integer "role"
  t.index ["university_id"], name: "index_users_on_university_id"
end

# Models

class University < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :staffs
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  self.inheritance_column = :role
  enum role: { Staff: 0, Clinician: 1 }
end

class Clinician < User
end

class Staff < User
  belongs_to :university
end

Staff.first.university # => returns instance of University
Clinician.first.university # => raises NoMethodError
University.first.staffs # => returns collection of Staff objects
University.first.clinicians # => raises NoMethodError
```

Note that there is no `type` column. It's been overridden by the `role:integer` column used for the `enum` by setting `self.inheritance_column = :role`. You can interact with the `enum` roles with the string/symbol representation (`"Staff"`, `Staff.new`, `User.first.Staff?`, `User.first.Staff!`, `User.new(role: "Staff")` and ActiveRecord takes care of converting that string to the right integer for the database queries.

For example, here's the query for `User.where(role: "Staff")`

```
SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."role" = 0
```

`Staff.all` returns the same result but the wording of the query is *slightly* different

```
SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."role" IN (0)
```

See this question for more detail: [Same Model with different columns Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45339248/same-model-with-different-columns-rails/45339611#45339611)

Comment: Thanks for bringing that up. I've been researching Single Table Inheritance and wondering how it would work with enums.

Comment: I have tried implementing STI based on that question and can't seem to get methods to be recognized... I am considering just doing away with enums and using the type column as described in the post. Is there a downside to that that you know of? Any reason to keep enums around?

Comment: If you're going to combine them you need to make sure you're overriding the default `type` column for the STI. Adding `self.inheritance_table = :role` to the `User` model should do it. The advantage of enums is that integers are much faster to look up especially if there are a lot of records, and they give you a few handy methods for free. @mike9182

Comment: Thanks Simon - do you have a recommendation about which I collect in my user signup form? (enum role or STI Type?) Can I have whichever I collect on signup set the other one without having to ask the user to define their role and their type with separate form fields?

Comment: @mike9182 You should use only one of these columns, not both. If you're combining STI and `enum` and using `role` as your `enum` column then you should not have a `type` column: the `enum` role is the same as your `STI` type. You interact with the string versions, and Rails converts to `role` integers for the database. I updated the answer with more code examples that hopefully demonstrate this. Let me know if it's not clear

Comment: Thanks M. Simon! I am going to try to set it up as you have described. If you are interested in any consulting work on this project, it would be great to have an extra hand. I'm at mikebaker@gmail.com

Answer (score 1):

You can give a condition to the `validates` call in your User.rb model:

```
validates :university, presence: true, if: lambda { self.role.to_s == 'staff' }
# watch out for symbol vs. string in your self.role array
```

And I think (never done it but I guess that would work) you can do this for the `:clinician` role:

```
validates :university, presence: false, if: lambda { self.role.to_s == 'clinician' }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! This gives me the following NoMethodError:

undefined method `include?' for nil:NilClass

Comment: This means the `self.role` is not an array, and therefore is not populated (yet) with the assigned role(s). You can do a simple `raise self.inspect` in the if's lambda to see what you have access from here. Also, you probably want a `validates :role, presence: true` **before** the `validates` I suggested, as if you did not selected/set role(s), the `validates :role` will fail

Comment: You are right that for some reason the signup form isn't passing or saving the role properly. Can you tell why? I added the form to the original question.

Comment: using `enum`, `role` should either be `'staff'` or `'clinician'`, it will not be an `Array`. it should be `validates :university, presence: true, if: lambda { self.role == 'staff' }`. and I don't think `presence: false` will work. That means you're telling the validation not to do a `presence` check

Comment: @m.simonborg yeah I am not sure about the `presence: false`... I would have to take a look at the `validates` implementation. Also, +1 for the enum

Comment: @mike9182 I think you have to use strings in your enum and not symbols, not sure about this one though...

Comment: `enum` should take symbols because you're also defining helper methods of that name, but they will receive `to_s` when you call `role` and be represented as strings

Comment: Sorry I'm a bit new at rails - it sounds like the verdict is that the enum should take symbols, but does this mean I need to change my signup form in some way to get it to appropriately save the role? Currently, when I select a role and complete the signup form, validation fails saying that I must select a role.

Comment: @mike9182 make sure you are allowing the `role` value to be passed (see in your `strong_parameters`), if you want this feature (User can select his own role). When this is done, do a simple inspect on the received params right before the user creation

Comment: Thanks! This is very helpful.