# Rails How to create a Model, Controller and View using Inheritance?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord, single-table-inheritance

I am working on this application that uses inheritance on models, but it is getting this **error message** on the view:

**superclass mismatch for class BankTransfer**

I have created an MVC called “payment_methods” Using the scaffold command:

```
rails g scaffold payment_methods type:string is_active:boolean
```

In the model file, **payment_method.rb**, I have included the classes:

```
class PaymentMethod < ApplicationRecord

end

class BankTransfer < PaymentMethod

end

class PayPal < PaymentMethod
end
```

Using rails console, with the commands: `BankTransfer.create` and `Paypal.create`, was possible to create on database the objects.

So running on rails console: `PaymentMethod.all` i get the return (that shows me that it was correctly save on the database):

```
PaymentMethod.all
  PaymentMethod Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "payment_methods".* FROM "payment_methods"                                                                 
 =>                                                                  
[#<Boleto:0x00007f995d403000                                         
  id: 1,                                                             
  type: "BankTransfer",                                                    
  is_active: nil,                                                    
  created_at: Fri, 15 Jul 2022 16:46:29.759160000 UTC +00:00,        
  updated_at: Fri, 15 Jul 2022 16:46:29.759160000 UTC +00:00>,       
 #<Stripe:0x00007f995d402da8
  id: 2,
  type: "PayPal",
  is_active: nil,
  created_at: Fri, 15 Jul 2022 16:46:56.087921000 UTC +00:00,
  updated_at: Fri, 15 Jul 2022 16:46:56.087921000 UTC +00:00>]
```

The views and the controller were created automatically.

**index.html.erb**

```
<div id="payment_methods">
  <% @payment_methods.each do |payment_method| %>
    <%= render payment_method %>
    <p>
      <%= link_to "Show this payment method", payment_method %>
    </p>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

**payment_methods_controller.rb**

```
class PaymentMethodsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_payment_method, only: %i[ show edit update destroy ]

  def index
    @payment_methods = PaymentMethod.all
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @payment_method = PaymentMethod.new
  end

(...)

  private
    def set_payment_method
      @payment_method = PaymentMethod.find(params[:id])
    end

    def payment_method_params
      params.require(:payment_method).permit(:type, :is_active)
    end
end
```

What should I fix to be able to see a list of payment methods on the frontend. Instead of the error message **superclass mismatch for class**.

Comment: Hi @muistooshortm, thanks for reply. Currently, it has no "Stripe" I will implement the API interaction inside the class later. In the beginning, I need to be able to load the different objects that were saved in the database in the frontend. For example, I could change "Stripe" to "BankTransfer", then in the frontend, I would have a simple table with. | id | type | is_active | columns| , when I call `PaymentMethod.all`

Comment: I am trying to implement this solution for an inheritance, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45339248/same-model-with-different-columns-rails, but getting an error message.

Comment: I hope that I could explain the issue, but if needed, I can add more information.

Comment: Sorry for the "Strype" spelling, It was an error when creating the issue. Changed to "BankTransfer" for a better explanation.

Comment: I deleted the database and changed the names for `StripePaymentMethod`,  created a new database, and it worked. Thanks, if you want to post the answer I will mark it as solved, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to have a `'Stripe'` value in your `payment_methods.type` column then you'll need to have a `Stripe` class that looks like this:

```
class Stripe < PaymentMethod
  # ...
end
```

Similarly for other `payment_methods.type` values.

The problem is that the `stripe` gem defines `module Stripe`, that's where your "superclass mismatch" error comes from.

The easiest solution would be to use a different name for your Stripe class, maybe `StripePaymentMethod` (and then `PayPalPaymentMethod`, `BankTransferPaymentMethod`, ... for consistency).